# R data table : Shifting rows of list type

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with a `list` type:

```
x = data.table(k = seq(1:5), l = list(c(4,5)))
> x
   k   l
1: 1 4,5
2: 2 4,5
3: 3 4,5
4: 4 4,5
5: 5 4,5
```

I am now trying to shift the `l` values by `1`:

```
x[, m:=shift(l, 1)]
> x
   k   l     m
1: 1 4,5 NA, 4
2: 2 4,5 NA, 4
3: 3 4,5 NA, 4
4: 4 4,5 NA, 4
5: 5 4,5 NA, 4
```

This produces a shift 'within' the list, and not across lists.(Aside: It's not clear why `NA` appears for rows `2-5`.) 
Whats the way out to get something like this:

```
x[magic]
> x
   k   l  m
1: 1 4,5 NA
2: 2 4,5 4,5
3: 3 4,5 4,5
4: 4 4,5 4,5
5: 5 4,5 4,5
```

Comment: Closing this as dup since a [better solution was recently implemented](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1595).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a manual shift, like the following.

```
x[, m := c(NA_real_, head(l, -1L))]
```

resulting in

> ```
>    k   l   m
> 1: 1 4,5  NA
> 2: 2 4,5 4,5
> 3: 3 4,5 4,5
> 4: 4 4,5 4,5
> 5: 5 4,5 4,5
> ```

For a larger shift, you could roll your own function.

```
mshift <- function(var, n) c(NA[1:n], head(var, -n))
```

Then use it to shift two places.

```
x[, m := mshift(l, 2)]
```

which gives, from the original data

> ```
>    k   l   m
> 1: 1 4,5  NA
> 2: 2 4,5  NA
> 3: 3 4,5 4,5
> 4: 4 4,5 4,5
> 5: 5 4,5 4,5
> ```

Obviously, this function is very basic and only shifts to the right (down).  If you wanted to, you could adjust the function to shift in the opposite direction and add some class checking/matching as well.

Comment: Maybe `NA_real_` to match the rest.

Comment: @Frank - I guess so, even though list elements usually aren't related.

Answer (score 2):

With `shift`, one option is to get the `shift` on the sequence of 'l', subset the 'l' based on that and assign it to new column 'm'.  By default, the `shift` returns with `fill = NA`.  So, those elements will be `NULL` in the 'm', which we can `replace` it to `NA` (if needed) or else removing those elements can be also done easily with `is.null`.

```
x[, m := l[shift(seq_along(l))]][, m := lapply(m, function(x) 
          replace(x, is.null(x), NA))]
x
#   k   l   m
#1: 1 4,5  NA
#2: 2 4,5 4,5
#3: 3 4,5 4,5
#4: 4 4,5 4,5
#5: 5 4,5 4,5
```

Or as @Frank mentioned, we can specify the logical index in 'i' while updating the 'm' to `NA_real_` for only those subset of elements specified in the 'i' and would be more efficient.

```
x[, m := l[shift(seq_along(l))]][sapply(m, is.null), m := .(.(NA_real_))]
```

---

Or in a compact way, we can change the `fill` to `0` and append `NA` at the beginning.  If the `shift` is greater than 1, use the `rep` to replicate the NA and append at the beginning.

```
x[,  m:= c(NA, l[shift(seq_along(l), fill = 0)])]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but liked the simplicity of @Richard.  Do you rate your answer better?

Comment: @jacquard  I opted this because your question was about using `shift`, otherwise, I would go with the simpler option.

Comment: Ok, my question was related to shifting in general see `magic` reference in my question. I am opting @Richard's answer as accepted because of the simplicity. Cheers!

Comment: @jacquard  No problem with that.